# Change value of variable every specific value of time c#

Tags: c#

I need to change some variable value depending on time. I mean: If i set time to 1000ms the value of variable must change every 1000ms etc.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of timer. If you're writing a Windows Forms application, then you'll probably want to use the [Windows Forms Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For WPF applications, you probably want a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For console applications and Windows Services, you'll want either [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Although you *can* use those in Windows Forms and WPF applications, they're more difficult to use than the specific timers for those frameworks.

Without more information about your specific application, I cannot provide more detailed recommendations or an example.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013 for that. I placed timer on Form